# When is the sequence convergent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $c$ be a real number, and 
$x_1 = \frac{c}{2}$. 
For $n\geq 2$, inductively define $x_n$ by $x_n = \frac{c}{2} +\frac{x_{n-1}^2}{2}$.

> The question is： for what $c$ the sequence is convergent?

---

We know that

1. If $c>1$, then $(x_n)$ is increasing, and $\lim x_n = +\infty $.
2. If $-3\leq c\leq 1$, then $x_n$  converges to $1-\sqrt{1-c}$.
3. If $c= -4$, then $(x_n)= -2,0,-2,0,\ldots$.
4. If $c= -8$, then $(x_n) = -4, 4,4,4,\ldots$, converges to 4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by 
$$f(x) = \frac{c}{2} + \frac{x^2}{2}$$

You want to study the sequence defined by $x_n = f(x_{n-1})$ and $x_1 = c/2$.

**Case 1 :** $c \geq 0$. Then studying the function $f$, you see that $f$ is strictly increasing on $[0, +\infty[$, and you have $f([0, +\infty[) = [\frac{c}{2}, +\infty[ \subset [0, +\infty[$. So $f$ is increasing on a stable interval that contains $x_1$, so your sequence is monotonous.

If $c > 1$, then $f$ has no fixed point so your sequence cannot converge.

If $0 \leq c \leq 1$, then $y = 1 + \sqrt{1-c}$ is a fixed point of $f$ and $\frac{c}{2} \in [0,y]$, so $[0,y]$ is a stable interval that contains $x_1$, so all the $x_n$ are in $[0,y]$. The sequence is therefore bounded and monotonous, so it converges.

**Case 2 :** $c < 0$. Let's note the easy following facts : first, $f$ is decreasing on $]-\infty,0]$ and increasing on $[0, +\infty[$. Moreover, $f$ has two fixed points that are $y_1 = 1- \sqrt{1-c} < 0$ and $y_2 = 1 + \sqrt{1-c} > 0$. You have also $f(-\sqrt{-c})= f(\sqrt{-c}) =0$. And you have the inequalities $-y_2 < -\sqrt{-c} < y_1$.

If $x_1 < -y_2 < 0$, then $x_2 > f(-y_2)=f(y_2)$ because $f$ is even. So after the second term, your sequence is strictly increasing in the stable interval $[y_2, +\infty[$ that contains no fixed point of $f$ (except $y_2$), so it cannot converge. This case $x_1 < -y_2$ is equivalent to $\frac{c}{2} < -1 - \sqrt{1-c}$, and it happens if and only if $c < -8$.

If $0 > x_1 > - \sqrt{-c}$, then the interval $[-\sqrt{-c}, 0]$ is stable. Because $f$ is decreasing on this interval, the sequences $(x_{2n})$ and $(x_{2n+1})$ are one increasing and the other decreasing. Now you can prove that the only possibility is that they both converge (to the fixed point $y_1$ of $f$), so $(x_n)$ converges. This case $x_1 > - \sqrt{-c}$ is equivalent to $\frac{c}{2} > - \sqrt{-c}$, and it happens if and only if $-4 < c < 0$.

The cases $c =-4$ and $c= -8$ are easy to solve, as you noticed.

It remains the case where $-8 < c < -4$, i.e. $-y_2 < x_1 < -\sqrt{-c}$. In this case, I think that your sequence can either converge, either be periodic. But I don't know how to compute explicitely the cases where it is periodic (for instance, the real solution of $c^3 + 8c^2 + 16c + 64 = 0$ gives the periodic solution $x_1 = \frac{c}{2}$, $x_2 = \sqrt{-c}$, $x_3 = 0$, $x_4 = \frac{c}{2}$, etc...) even if I think that there exists only a countable number of them.

Comment: Since there is no complete answer appeared, I should accept this answer to close the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Solve the equation
$$g=\frac{c}{2}+\frac{g^2}{2}$$ and then prove if $g$ exists.

Comment: Sorry, I dont get it.